# How can I optimise this Linq query to remove the unnecessary SELECT Count(*)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have three tables, Entity, Period and Result. There is a 1:1 mapping between Entity and Period and a 1:Many between Period and Result.

This is the linq query:

```
int id = 100;
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

from p in db.Periods
where p.Entity.ObjectId == id && p.Start == start
select new { Period = p, Results = p.Results })
```

This is relevant parts of the  generated SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[EntityId], [t2].[PeriodId], [t2].[Value], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Result] AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[PeriodId] = [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [value2]

FROM [dbo].[Period] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Entity] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [t0].[EntityId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Result] AS [t2] ON [t2].[PeriodId] = [t0].[Id]
WHERE ([t1].[ObjectId] = 100) AND ([t0].[Start] = '2010-02-01 00:00:00')
```

Where is the SELECT Count(*) coming from and how can I get rid of it? I don't need a count of the "Results" for each "Period" and it slows the query down by an order of magnitude.

Comment: I think the count is actually so it can turn your Cartesian product result into a 1-many result. So if you have many periods which have many results, it knows the number of results each period should have, when it transforms the result.

Comment: I guess the reason of this behavior is that the LinqToSql is trying to prepare a number of rows of the nested collection for some reasons. Try to play with `DeferredLoadingEnabled` property of your data context, or any other about **Lazy Loading**. Anyway, LinqToSql not supported now. Switch to EF.

Comment: @Genius - "LinqToSql is not supported now?" It's in the latest version of .NET 4.0, it's still supported.  Maybe you don't support it but that's another story! :-P

Comment: It's like @Phill says, it needs to know the nr. of rows to put in the child collection "Results" for every entity

Comment: @Genius: I need eager loading which is why I'm projecting to an anonymous object and getting the results included.

Comment: I wonder if its worth manually creating the objects? ie. Use ExecuteQuery to run my custom SQL and create the collection myself by running through all the rows returned. The query with the count goes from 1 sec to 12 secs - so it should be worth it.

Comment: @dan We've been doing that recently on my current project, particularly on long queries. In particular we found that LINQ-to-SQL can only retrieve a single child collection per query, so if you want 2, 3 or more child objects it will make multiple database calls. It's much quicker for us to make the single, more complex, query as sproc from which we create objects. It's a bit of a pain, but works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Context.LoadOptions and specifying for Period to LoadWith(p => p.Results) to eager load the period with results without needing to project into an anonymous type.